# OnScrollListener for RecyclerView total scroll is inaccurate?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I implemented an OnScrollListener for a RecyclerView as follows:

```
new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        scrollY += dy;
    }
};
```

This should add up all the scroll changes so that scrollY holds the total vertical scroll of the RecyclerView.

But when I scroll down to the end of my list and scroll back up, the scroll value does not equal 0, but is positive (in my test example it ends at around 300).

What part of my implementation is wrong?

Comment: is `overScroll` mode on?

Comment: I didn't change overScroll, so it is the default value (OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS). I am suspecting that it maybe has something to do with fragment reinstanciation in the ViewPager, since the Recycler is inside a fragment inside a ViewPager, I will double check my fragment state restoration now. Are there known issues with OverScroll and OnScrollListener?

Comment: I ruled out that issue, as my fragments never get saved. I already suspected that, since I am using FragmentPagerAdapter and not FragmentStatePagerAdapter, but I just double checked with Logcat, it has nothing to do with fragment reinstanciation.

Comment: I'm still having the issue you first describe in your question. Looks like relying on the onScrolled callback doesn't yield an accurate total scroll... Everything works well if you drag the list back and forth without lifting your finger, but as soon as you fling, the value goes out of sync to what it really should be. Haven't managed to sort that out yet.

Comment: @brAzzi64 Yes, I figured the same. There is however a more accurate way of doing these calculations if you are using LinearLayoutManager. You can use it to get the current onscreen views and by then calling getTop() on one of them you can get a very precise positions of the views at least

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out and it was actually a timing issue. For those who might have the same problem as me at some point, here is what happened:

In my fragment I added an OnScrollListener to add up all dy to get the complete scrollY value for the RecyclerView:

```
new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        mScrollY += dy;
    }
};
```

In my RecyclerView rows, I wanted to use this mScrollY value, whenever the RecyclerView was scrolled, to respond with a parallax effect, so I implemented an OnScrollListener in the ViewHolder, like so:

```
new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        applyParallax(mScrollY); //mScrollY is calculated by fragment's OnScrollListener
    }
};
```

I figured, that since the ViewHolders got destroyed and reused, it was the most resource efficient to only add the child OnScrollListeners when needed.

The thing I didn't know about RecyclerView is that its OnScrollListeners are handled in sequence of addition (it's kinda obvious after the fact). Since the fragment's OnScrollListener was added first and the row's OnScrollListeners after, the fragments OnScrollListener was called last, resulting in the mScrollY value being updated *after* it had been handled by the row's OnScrollListeners, thus they missed the last update and stopped at the second to last mScrollY value, which was positive.

I fixed it by implementing all logic into the fragment's OnScrollListener like so (Note, that I only check the first child, since I only needed a parallax effect in the first row! If you have more effects in other places, you must loop through all current views in the LayoutManager):

```
new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        mScrollY += dy;
        LinearLayoutManager manager = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
        View firstChild = manager.getChildAt(0);
        if(firstChild.getId() == R.id.fpd_title_super){
            final PostDataAdapter.MainTitleViewHolder holder = (PostDataAdapter.MainTitleViewHolder)mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(firstChild);
            holder.dispatchScrollY(mScrollY);
        }
    }
};
```

And implementing a method into the ViewHolders:

```
public void dispatchScrollY(int scrollY){
    // handle parallax effect here
}
```

Now it works.

Comment: In case you still have problems with your srolling and parallax effects you can check this implementation: https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview

Comment: That is a nice library, I won't use it for now, as I want to stick to framework apis wherever possible, but this might be helpful for other people with this problem!